# Flask image not showing up despite using /static/

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I have a problem. When I use flask, I have to put the templates into the templates folder, but I can't get the images I use to show up on the website.

[My files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vObSB.png)

Original code:

```
<img src="/images/download.jpg" class="card-img-top cards" alt="...">
```

What I have tried:

```
<img src="/static/images/download.jpg" class="card-img-top cards" alt="...">
```

Could someone pls help me because I am stuck. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a static directory. Create a folder called `static` and move your images under it after which you can use the second link you have (`/static/images/....`)